# Add custom output layer to built-in (functional) keras model in R

Tags: r, keras

I am trying to use R keras to combine a built-in network architecture with a custom output layer. Specifically, I want a regression output for an architecture that was originally built for classification.

Here is a simple example of what I would want:

```
inlayer <- layer_input(shape = c(75, 75, 1))
N1 <- application_inception_v3(weights = NULL,
                               input_tensor = inlayer,
                               include_top = FALSE)
outlayer <- layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')

fullnet <- N1 %>% outlayer
```

However, the last line of code doesn't work - I get the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I think part of the problem is that the built-in network (N1) is defined using the functional API, so extra layers cannot be added sequentially using the `%>%` operator.

I have also tried defining my extra output layer as a separate architecture using the functional API, but I can't find a way to merge the two models:

```
N2_in <-  layer_input(shape = c(2048)) #note: output shape of N1
N2_out <- N2_in %>% layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')
N2 <- keras_model(N2_in, N2_out)

#try to merge with pipe again:
N1 %>% N2
```

Here is the error I get if I try merging with the pipe operator:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x7f88950ed748>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model'>) to a Tensor.
```

Any ideas on how to combine `N1` with either `outlayer` or `N2` are greatly appreciated  - and thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the functional api, you call layers/models with
tensors like `input` below, not with layers themselves.
Here is a working snippet that does what you want:

```r
library(keras)
input <- layer_input(shape = c(75, 75, 1))
#> Loaded Tensorflow version 2.6.0
input
#> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 75, 75, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'")

N1 <- application_inception_v3(weights = NULL,
                               input_tensor = input,
                               include_top = FALSE)

output_layer_instance <- layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')
output <- input %>% N1() %>% output_layer_instance()
output
#> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 1, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense/Sigmoid:0', description="created by layer 'dense'")

model <- keras_model(input, output)
model
#> Model
#> Model: "model"
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> Layer (type)                        Output Shape                    Param #     
#> ================================================================================
#> input_1 (InputLayer)                [(None, 75, 75, 1)]             0           
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> inception_v3 (Functional)           (None, 1, 1, 2048)              21802208    
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
#> dense (Dense)                       (None, 1, 1, 2)                 4098        
#> ================================================================================
#> Total params: 21,806,306
#> Trainable params: 21,771,874
#> Non-trainable params: 34,432
#> ________________________________________________________________________________
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Please don't forget to accept the answer.